# Regex match the immediate left occurrence of a repeated pattern based on a unique string

Tags: regex

I've been at this one for a while and can't quite work it out.

I'm trying to match the immediate left occurrence of a repeated pattern based on a unique pattern.

Say I have the following string

> DataColumn Caption="ColA" DataField="Col1Data" DataColumn Caption="ColB" DataField="Col2Data" DataColumn Caption="ColC" DataField="Col3Data" DataColumn Caption="ColD" DataField="Col4Data" DataColumn Caption="ColE" DataField="Col5Data" DataColumn Caption="ColF" DataField="Col6Data" DataColumn Caption="ColG" DataField="Col7Data" DataColumn Caption="ColH" DataField="Col8Data" DataColumn Caption="ColI" DataField="Col9Data"

And I'd like to **match** (to do a find/replace) the value of the `Caption` immediately before `DataField="Col8Data"` so that I can change it's value from "Col" to something else.

The closest I can get is to put a greedy non-capture group in front of the pattern like so `(?:.*)Caption="(.*)"\sDataField="Col8Data"`

This however gives me a **match** of the whole string between the first `Caption="Col"` with my found col in a capture group (not what I'm after)

Help is much appreciated

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that the value of `Caption` is always different, hence why I was trying to match it with the `"(.*)"`.
I've updated the string sample to show

Comment: A trick that I use a lot with regex is that if I want to match everything between a pair of quotes, I match the first quote, and then any non-quote character, and then the second quote.  It sounds like since you used `.*` to match the contents between quotes, it picked up a whole bunch more text.  If you use my approach, then you should be able to capture the `Caption = "[^"]*"` that directly precedes the `DataField="Col8Data"`.

Comment: `(?<=DataField=\"Col7Data\" DataColumn Caption=\")[^\"]*(?=\" DataField=\"Col8Data\")` should get the value of before Col8Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try doing a find/replace using lookarounds.  Try finding the following pattern:

```
(?<=Caption=)"[^"]+"(?=\s*DataField="Col8Data")
```

You may confirm for yourself that this will match the `"Col"` value sandwiched in between the `Caption` and `DataField` terms you want.  Then, replace with whatever value you want.

### Demo

Comment: Perfect! It matches the surrounding quotes too but that's no issue.

Comment: @SeanMissingham I wasn't sure whether or not you also wanted the quotes.  No big deal, you may just replace with quotes.

Comment: Edit incoming, I forgot to include something else that actually made this harder

Comment: @SeanMissingham No, this doesn't make it harder, q.v. my updated answer.

Comment: Maybe not for a regex wizard, but that was where I came completely unstuck. Thank you Tim.